# Sub-Query with group by and Case Statement

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, subquery, case

I have two tables , one is **Country** table and another one is **Threshold** Table.

**Country** table has columns and data like this :

<kbd>**`ID`**</kbd>        <kbd>**`Country`**</kbd>   <kbd>**`Count`**</kbd>     <kbd>**`Year`**</kbd>      
<kbd>`00001`</kbd>     <kbd>`India`</kbd>     <kbd>`200`</kbd>       <kbd>`2011`</kbd>      
<kbd>`00001`</kbd>     <kbd>`India`</kbd>     <kbd>`400`</kbd>       <kbd>`2013`</kbd>      
<kbd>`00001`</kbd>     <kbd>`Japan`</kbd>     <kbd>`1000`</kbd>      <kbd>`2011`</kbd>      
<kbd>`00001`</kbd>     <kbd>`Japan`</kbd>     <kbd>`550`</kbd>       <kbd>`2013`</kbd>      
<kbd>`00001`</kbd>     <kbd>`China`</kbd>     <kbd>`400`</kbd>       <kbd>`2011`</kbd>

And the **Threshold** table has data like this :

<kbd>**`ID`**</kbd>            <kbd>**`Low Value`**</kbd>     <kbd>**`High Value`**</kbd>     
<kbd>`00001`</kbd>         <kbd>`500`</kbd>           <kbd>`1000`</kbd>

That means if the `Count >= 500` then **Low** , if the `Count > 500 and < 1000` the **Medium** and if `Count >= 1000` then **High**.

I want a result like this :

<kbd>**`Country`**</kbd>   <kbd>**`Count`**</kbd>     <kbd>**`Threshold`**</kbd>      <kbd>**`Low Value`**</kbd>  <kbd>**`High Value`**</kbd>   
<kbd>`India`</kbd>     <kbd>`600`</kbd>       <kbd>`Medium`</kbd>         <kbd>`500`</kbd>        <kbd>`1000`</kbd>         
<kbd>`Japan`</kbd>     <kbd>`1550`</kbd>      <kbd>`High`</kbd>           <kbd>`500`</kbd>        <kbd>`1000`</kbd>         
<kbd>`China`</kbd>     <kbd>`400`</kbd>       <kbd>`Low`</kbd>            <kbd>`500`</kbd>        <kbd>`1000`</kbd>

So I want to write a `SQL query` .

I am already using this query :

```
SELECT C.Country,C.Count
,CASE WHEN C.Count <= T.Low_Value THEN 'Low' WHEN C.Count BETWEEN T.High_Value AND T.Low_Value THEN 'Medium' ELSE 'High' END AS Threshold,
T.Low_Value, T.High_Value FROM 
(SELECT ID,Country,Sum(Count) AS Count 
FROM Country 
WHERE ID=00001 
GROUP BY ID,Country) C 
JOIN Threshold T 
ON C.ID = T.ID
```

But this query is giving error.

Can anyone one please suggest me how to implement this ?

> I am using **Oracle**
>
> The error is **ORA-00979 : not a GROUP BY expression**

`**This query is just for representation**`

Comment: The inner query is running fine

Comment: That's a **case expression**, not a case statement.

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT` is a reserved word. Either pick a different alias or use double quotes around the alias.

```
SELECT C.Country,
       C."Count",
       CASE WHEN C."Count" <= T.Low_Value THEN 'Low'
            WHEN C."Count" BETWEEN T.High_Value AND T.Low_Value THEN 'Medium'
            ELSE 'High' END AS Threshold,
       T.Low_Value,
       T.High_Value
FROM   (
  SELECT ID,Country,Sum("Count") AS "Count"
  FROM Country 
  WHERE ID=00001 
  GROUP BY ID,Country
) C 
JOIN Threshold T 
ON C.ID = T.ID
```

Comment: That was a typo :)

Comment: I am not exactly using this query , I have used Count for understanding . I have not used Count as alias .

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using this :

```
SELECT Country
      ,Total
      ,CASE WHEN Total <= Low_Value THEN 'Low'
            WHEN Total BETWEEN Low_Value AND High_Value THEN 'Medium'
        ELSE 'High' END AS Threshold
      FROM (SELECT ID
          ,Country
          ,Low_Value
          ,High_Value
          ,SUM(Count) Total
         FROM (SELECT C.ID
             ,C.Country
             ,C.Count
             ,T.Low_Value
             ,T.High_Value
           FROM Country C JOIN Threshold T
           ON C.ID=T.ID
           WHERE C.ID =00001)
        GROUP BY Country,Low_Value,High_Value)
```